# Undefined symbols for architecture while using dylib C++

Tags: xcode, cocoa, linker, dylib

This is the procedure I am following to create dylib and using it ,please help me I am new to dylib .

I am creating dylib for c++ in xcode I have given **Installation Directory @rpath** this is my C++ code

Add.hpp:

```
#define EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
class Add
{
public:
    EXPORT void HelloWorld(const char *);
    EXPORT int AddTwo(int a,int b);
};
```

Add.cpp:

```
void Add::HelloWorld(const char * s)
{
     AddPriv *theObj = new AddPriv;
     theObj->HelloWorldPriv(s);
     delete theObj;
};
int Add::AddTwo(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

After creating dylib in other project using Copy files in build phases, copying it to Frameworks, I am able to see it in `Sample.App/Contents/Frameworks/Mylib.dylib`. In Build Settings, **Runpath Search Paths** is set to `@executable_path/../Frameworks`. I added header in root folder given **Header Search Paths** `$(SRCROOT)`.

The error I get is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Add::AddTwo(int, int)", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Edit:

```
$ nm -gU ****/AddTest.app/Contents/Frameworks/libAdd.dylib 
0000000000001170 T __ZN3Add10HelloWorldEPKc
0000000000001220 T __ZN3Add6AddTwoEii
```

able to see symboles in lib and otool output is:

```
$ otool -L libAdd.dylib 
    @rpath/libAdd.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved by adding library to **Link Binary with Libraries** in build phases